# Where do you get games for the click wheel iPods?

Tags: ipod

I've got an iPod classic, and I can't for the life of me find any of the games that work with it on the iTunes Store.

I know they are there, because I've seen them recently I just can't find them.

Comment: Hy.. i don`t have iPod click wheel games in my app store menu .. how i can find it ? or what can i do ? i have iTunes version 10

Comment: Maybe you have to have the iPod plugged in? I doubt it. Though. I'm fairly sure that it's just there.

Comment: It looks like Apple have recently removed the clickwheel games from the iTunes store. At least I got the game I was after when I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the iTunes store, click the triangle at the end of the App Store tab at the top, and choose iPod Click Wheel Games at the very bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I found it independently and was coming back to say so. You get the rep for answering before me :)

Comment: I did... see the tick up there... That means I accepted it. Also the rep for answering was the rep for me accepting it.